# Multilevel filter in read operation in OData

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need help in filter to read OData. I need filter as following while performing `oModel.read()`.

```
(
  ((USERID EQ 'KSA') OR (USERID EQ 'KSW'))
   AND
  ((USERID NE 'KUMARNISH2') OR (USERID NE 'KUMARNISH3'))
)
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score -1):

you should use filters like below:

```
           oModel.read("/PromoResponsesSet", null, ["$filter= ((USERID EQ
           'KSA') OR (USERID EQ 'KSW')) AND  ((USERID NE 'KUMARNISH2') OR
            (USERID NE 'KUMARNISH3')) "], false,function(orData, response)   
        {  
          },function(oError)   
        {  
            console.log("Error in read");
        }
```